# How to efficiently delete text in Vim while in insert mode

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

Using Vim, I want to efficiently delete text while I am in insert mode. I can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. What does is it mean? Should I stop using <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and only use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to edit efficiently? If yes, then should I disable <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in my .vimrc (like what I have done for arrow keys)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use `Ctrl-o` to do a single normal mode command. Eg if you start a sentence, and decide you want to deleting it and start again, you could enter `Ctrl-o d(` while in insert mode.

To be honest though, I've been using vim for at least 5 years, and I never feel the need for this. I think the key trick for vim is to make entering normal mode really easy. Esc is a bit of a pain to hit honestly, it is pretty far away in most keyboards. I remap Capslock to Ctrl to help with this. This makes the `Ctrl-[` shortcut really easy to hit for entering normal mode. You can also use `inoremap kj <Esc>` to make entering kj leave insert mode (you rarely type kj in typing, even with code).

The ultimate solution is to remap Capslock to Escape. I find though that mapping Capslock to Ctrl is a lot more useful in many other programs so that binding is more useful in general.

Comment: Take a look at [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) - it allows you to have *both* control and escape on your Caps Lock (depending whether you press it in a combination or alone) - it's really awesome!

Comment: That is a pretty interesting tool. My only concern would be when I hit caplock to get ready to do a shortcut using ctrl, and then change my mind - would releasing capslock and sending an accidental escape cause problems?

Comment: If you hold the key long enough before releasing, it will emit control, not escape. So if you change your mind after pressing caps, just wait a moment before releasing it (the delay is configurable). This may sound complicated, but it works :-)

Comment: No that makes perfect sense, and is a perfect solution to my concern. Looks like a good addition to my linux setup.

Answer (score 4):

Vim is a modal editor. This means there are advantages to using the right mode for the right task.

General Rules of thumb:

- Make a quick correction as you type in insert mode - use backspace (or maybe `<c-w>`)
- Need to delete/change a word or something larger you should probably jump back to normal mode and do a `d` with a motion or `c` with a motion.
- Need to delete many lines then it is time to break out macros or ex commands. e.g `:g/foo/d`

Few things to remember:

- You should only be in insert mode for short bursts. Normal mode should be considered your default or "normal" mode
- It is often a good practice to making your changes work well with the `.` command. e.g. using `daw`, `>`,  or `ciw` and repeating the change via `.`
- Vim's modal nature makes the undo history nice and chunky. Abusing insert mode will make the undo history less useful.

Comment: Great answer! I would only add the recommendation to make switching modes as easy as possible, mostly by moving the Escape key to a very convenient position (e.g. Caps Lock).

Answer (score 0):

No, in my opinion, if you make a mistake it's very easy (and efficient) to simply hit backspace a time or two compared to pressing CTRL-h. Here are some other insert mode shortcuts http://usevim.com/2012/12/14/vim-101-insert-mode-shortcuts/ such as CTRL-w, which deletes the word before the cursor. Not using arrow keys is *more* efficient because no time is wasted moving your hand back and forth. This does not seem the case with backspace because the alternative is more complex (two-key combination vs one) for the same result.

See `:help ins-special-keys`

Disclaimer: 6 month Vim user